# Pass data from one action to another in yii2

Tags: php, json, post, yii2

I am trying to implement shopping cart for my Yii2 site. There are N calculation forms depending on how many products user put in a cart.

```
<form class="calculator" id="calc1">
    <div id="calc_left_half">
            <br>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="calculation_input" id="regular_input_1" name="regular_input" value="0" onkeyup="order()" onchange="order()"> Put A value
            <br>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="calculation_input" id="angular_input_1" name="angular_input" value="0" onkeyup="order()" onchange="order()"> Put B value
            <br>
    </div>
    <div id="calc_right_half">
        <span class="order"> SUM: <span class="color_result result" id="result_color_1">0</span> $<br>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="calculator" id="calc2">
    <div id="calc_left_half">
            <br>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="calculation_input" id="regular_input_1" name="regular_input" value="0" onkeyup="order()" onchange="order()"> Put A value
            <br>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="calculation_input" id="angular_input_1" name="angular_input" value="0" onkeyup="order()" onchange="order()"> Put B value
            <br>
    </div>
    <div id="calc_right_half">
        <span class="output"> SUM: <span class="color_result result" id="result_color_1">0</span><br>
    </div>
</form>

<a id="order" class="btn btn-success btn-send cart-button" href="index.php?r=site/create-pdf?>"><b>ORDER</b></a>
```

Function order() makes some calculation and assigns "output" span innerHtml to result. I 
My question is how to pass input values and "output" innerHtml value to action(site/create-pdf). I would like to create a pdf using mpdf extention with this values.

Side newbee question: Is it good idea to use json or xml for this purpose.

Thanks guys

Comment: With a hidden input that gets populated in the order function?

Comment: Could you give me some more details how it can be done?

Comment: Create a single form (why do you have several?), add an input (type hidden), add JS to your order() function and update the hidden input's value. With this a regular form gets submitted. Are you familiar with HTML/JS/PHP, which knowledge do you have? My suggestion is quite basic, so I guess there is something that I haven't understood in your question. So why do you have several forms? BTW: your id attributes are not unique.

Comment: I have multiple forms to have a non-unique ids for my inputs(this is required by calculation script). About my knowledge I am missing requests knowledge. Probably I will use POST requests but don't know how to implement them yet

Comment: I don't get it. A simple form with a hidden field should do it, IMO. And I don't see a reason why you have non-unique ids - this is invalid html. Also I noticed that some span tags don't get closed.

Comment: Please ignore mistakes this is just an example I've created to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use GET request. Pass paramater to url and use this
   parameter in other action.
2. Or you can use

```html
$this->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue'
```

Yii2 global variable in other actions.

Comment: In this case I will need an additional js script that changes url every time user changes input value, right? And one more thing: I would like to use POST to avoid too long urls.